# Why does my kali linux 2016.1 bootable usb not boot?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, 64-bit, kali-linux

I am trying to make a kali linux 2016.1 bootable usb using a sandisk 32gb usb.

Ive downloaded the .iso for the 64-bit, 32-bit and light 64-bit version. Also the 64-bit torrent version. And tried to make a bootable usb with these file's using:

- universal usb installer
- linux live usb creator
- win32diskmanager
- rufus

In most cases the usb gets installed with the proper files (at least i think so) and when i boot and press f11, i select my usb to boot from, and then it just skips to the windows boot.

When i use win32diskmanager it corrupts 26gb of my usb and doesnt install kali properly at all. I then have to use diskpart in cmd to remove the corrupted partitions and create new ones for my usb.

I also thought the usb was the problem, so i installed ubuntu on it using universal usb installer. And that was succesfull in the first try.

I don't know what the problem is and cant find other people on forums with the same problem. Can you please help me?

My specs: windows 10 64-bit version on a MSI GP60 2QE LEOPARD laptop

Answer (score 0):

I assume your laptop is in UEFI mode.

Coming to your problem Yes using win32diskmanager will corrupt your USB but it will work for UEFI and if it does not work try a different USB.
Rufus will not make your USB bootable for Kali Linux(if your laptop is in UEFI mode) as Kali Linux directly does not support UEFI install. If you want to continue using Rufus/UUI you will have to make EFI/BOOT folder and put BOOTx64.EFI and grubx64.efi after writing your USB. But here you will have to manually install Kali Linux from GRUB terminal.
And if nothing works try Grub2win for installation.
Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your laptop might have safeboot enabled, this can make it so that you only boot directly into Windows. When you press F11 to you see an option to disable safe boot? If so you can retry with it disabled.

If that doesn't work open the BIOS/UEFI and ensure that in the boot options menu that USB is checked as allowed.