# Why is a bootable USB not detected during boot? (Installed: Parrot OS, USB: Ultramarine Linux)

Tags: boot, bootable-media, liveusb, parrot-os

I created a bootable USB using rufus4.3 (build 2090) for Ultramarine Linux 38.
It is not being detected during startup, and I directly see the grub menu for the installed OS (Parrot 5.3).
(Similar situation as [Why does my kali linux 2016.1 bootable usb not boot?](https://superuser.com/questions/1115336/) but instead of Windows, it's Parrot)

I checked if the USB had the boot flag as per this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15231218) answer, it does. I also did the same with the USB that I used to install the Parrot OS for comparison.

`lsblk` and `fdisk -l` screenshots attached below.

**What I have tried:**

- Secure boot off (was already off due to replacing Windows with Parrot, but double checked)
- Resetting UEFI settings (but secure boot kept off)
- Fast boot off
- Enabling CSM as per [Boot from USB not working - Acer Aspire E1-522](https://superuser.com/questions/863018/)
- Disabling fastboot (https://superuser.com/a/512108/1366832)
- Set removable drive as boot option #1 (and parrot as the last boot option)
- Using all 3 available USB ports in case it was an issue with a port

**Update**:
I tried to boot using the USB on a 2018 Lenovo ideapad 320, and it was able to successfully enter live boot.
I tried using Rufus on the other USB (that had parrot) - same result
Using Balena Etcher instead of Rufus (both USBs) did not make a difference.

**System Information:**
2013 Acer Aspire ZC-105 All-in-one Desktop
As per `inxi -F`: `"UEFI: American Megatrends v: P11-A1 date: 08/29/2013"`
AMD A4-5000
Problematic USB: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 16 GB

`lsblk` results for context:
[image: lsblk result: sdb is ultramarine, sdc is parrot]
`fdisk -l` showing boot flag on problematic USB containing Ultramarine Linux
[image: ultramarine fdisk]
`fdisk -l` showing boot flag for the USB that was used to install Parrot:
[image: parrot usb fdisk]

Comment: Word of advice: do not enable CSM as an attempt to fix booting issue when your existing OS(es) are installed for UEFI booting / withs CSM disabled. It could end up causing you to have new installation(s) that you don't really want / can't be multi-booted with the way you like. If you can't UEFI boot a drive, focusing on fixing the drive. (Or see if there's general settings in your UEFI that prevent USB boot.)

Comment: Thank you, something to keep in mind for the future. None of the other questions or answers that I read mentioned this risk. Luckily, there was no adverse impact this time, and parrot still boots normally.

Comment: Also to keep in mind Secure Boot has nothing to do with it. As always, redo the media - use another tool if needed, like Balena Etcher or Ventoy (multi-boot) after assuring the original ISO is fine. Then it all boils down to the proper firmware selections, sometimes rebooting with the stick connected is needed, it depends on some factor, none that you address. And, by the way, you have UEFI, not BIOS, as any PC does since 2012! Do NOT blindly apply suggestions from the BIOS era, like your SE link, they won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **USB drives were being detected as hard disk drives**, and **not as removable devices**.
uncovery's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1628568/1366832) pointed me to look at the "Hard Disk Drive Priority" option in the "Boot Options" tab.
I had to change the priority to have the USB before the computer's hard drive with parrot on it.

Unfortunately, still unable to actually boot into ultramarine, getting `start_image() returned Unsupported`, but that is something for another question.